# Does WordPress refer to any files outside of the main install folder (and database)?

Tags: database, wordpress, file, installation, directory

Meaning, if I install WordPress in the /wp folder... would any files in the main root of the domain folder "/" be accessed, or any other folder outside of the /wp folder for that matter?  Meaning, are all of the WordPress files continuously self-contained to just the install folder (/wp in my case) and it's subfolders?

(Thus, if this is true, to remove WordPress, can we just delete the install folder...and vice-versa, if we install into a particular folder, we know no other files/folder would be affected?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WordPress does not depend on any files outside of the WordPress root directory, *under normal circumstances*.

There are ways to setup WordPress so you have dependencies outside of the WordPress directory. For example, you can specify alternate paths for the `wp-content` and `uploads` directory.

It's also fairly common to update the `wp-config.php` file to reference another file, outside of your web root, that contains all of your database credentials.

Out of the box however WordPress is completely self contained.